# Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Tags: android

After updating `android` to `8.0.0` facing this error

Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session :

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113.

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

I have also tried this

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

but not working

Comment: Are you getting this error while installing on emulator or device?

Comment: i am facing this issue in device(huawie mate 10 lite)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by replacing

implementation

```
'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

with

implementation group:

```
'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
```